# How to handle co-worker's loud voices?

Tags: professionalism, unprofessional-behavior

A recently hired co-worker has the habit of almost constantly discussing everything no matter how important or trivial the subject is and that is no problem for me but his rather loud voice is my problem with him. My desk is located rather close to said co-worker, and the loud talking voice is wearing on me. I have tried to separate my desk to minimize the effect but to no avail.

This is not about someone who makes loud weird unrecognizable voices, it's about someone who discusses and talks in a very loud voice.

I am considering politely pointing out that the loud voice is annoying to me (and I suspect others).

Suggestions?

Comment: is your CW hearing impaired?

Comment: @ChristopherEstep While similar, I don't think they're quite the same. The question you link is about a coworker who makes lots of unconscious "idle" noises. This question is about someone who talks loudly. I think the situations are different enough to warrant a new question.

Comment: @DavidK There are a ridiculous number of questions on this. Searching on just "loud" reveals plenty of questions that can give suggestions for dealing with a loud coworker. I'm not linking them all.

Comment: @ChristopherEstep I searched and I didn't find any, all other questions were about coworkers making weird noises but this is not the case here.

Comment: @ChristopherEstep I see [loud and unprofessional](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/59451/loud-and-unprofessional-employee), [loud and bossy](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17751/problems-with-loud-bossy-colleague), [loud meetings](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/24084/etiquette-on-loud-boardroom-meetings), and [loud conversations](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/70508/how-to-deal-with-coworkers-having-loud-conversations). The last is the only one I think could be a dupe. It's marked as a dupe of yours, though I don't think it should be.

Comment: Make it the culture to take discussions elsewhere.  The water cooler/coffee machine is a good place for informal discussions.   If needed, get posters that say "Working area; please take extended discussions elsewhere".

Comment: @DavidK I agree. I have seen several questions closed as "duplicates" that are not so. This question like the others is about a coworker who is making conscious, loud noises, not unconscious unintentional noises.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply go to him and politely tell him he has a strong voice which sometimes breaks your focus so you would really appreciate it if he could compensate his strong voice by speaking less loudly.

Answer (score 1):

Technology may save the day. Personally I use **sound-isolating** headphones and FM radio or online music, as well as so many programmers (so I do not care if anybody sees it as passive aggressive). I'd say let bygones be bygones. Guy might be offended, forget, ignore your comment or just be incapable to stay quiet. Note that [good ones](https://www.amazon.es/Beyer-Dynamic-770-PRO-Auriculares/dp/B01G8K70GW) cost $$$, and frugal person, like me, might end paying twice. Yet I see it as a fair price for the comfort. A drawback of headphones is that you might miss a manager sneaking behind, and seeing you complaining on work condition in social media, so will have to stop it.

I have seen people who use **earplugs**, yet I never dared something so radical myself, being afraid to look uncool / passive-aggressive so cannot comment how efficient are those

Some innovative and sometimes non-orthodox noise reduction ideas are floating around. One of startups, **HushMe** fights noise at the source with a special mask. It, regretfully, only reduces noise about 50%. Still, if you want make a joke just say want to see something funny gadget, yet the solution is a bit premature, headphones or telling straight might be safer bet. But let's not give up hope for improved technologies.

UPDATE. Just found potentially cheaper solution: create noise yourself, preferably white one, to hum the unpleasant co-worker noises. **White noise devices** or apps are quite inexpensive. I found this solution at a list of noise reduction solutions at https://snapcab.com/pods/escaping-the-noise-of-open-workspaces. ( I am not affiliated with any producers of dividers, white noise, or snapcab webmaster, swear) . Possible drawback - white noise is know to induce sleep, not sure is there such thing as upbeat white noise. Some doctors are worried that true white noise might be harmful, up to cause premature brain aging due to lack of structure https://gizmodo.com/study-claims-white-noise-can-damage-your-brain-but-don-1828804061. You get what you are paying a milder noise, such as pink one might be a better solution.

Comment: Unless you gift this to a good friend as a joke I think this can be taken realy poorly by the coworker.

Comment: @AlexandreAudin - agreed.  It would be taken as passive-aggressive, which it absolutely is.  I think a non-confrontational direct approach would be less fraught with dramatic peril.... which, I now see, you suggested in your own answer.

Comment: How are any of these solutions better than just telling the guy to be quieter?

Comment: Headphones would not create discomfort for the loud employee. Talking directly might work depending well if topic started can ask him in friendly manner, otherwise the new employee might become enemy. Topic poster, as a technical person might doubt his communication skills or fears a conflict. What if new employee promises to be quiet and forget tomorrow? Fancy gadget discussions might be a way to defuse situation (or aggravate - up to reader to take the risk or not).

Comment: I agree with this.   The guy at the desk next to me talks to himself loudly all day long.  I don't want to insist he stop because I can tell its his way of working through problems and probably helps his productivity.  I bought some good noise canceling over-ear headphones and its not been a problem since.   Over 50% of the time there is nothing playing in them, they are just filtering out things.

Comment: I wasted  a hunderd on Senhaiser 598 Closed Back, yet they would not isolate me completely, so I upgraded to Beyerdynamics 770 32Ohm (32 means that they might work without dedicated amplifier, 16Ohm are fine fine with any phone or mp3 player), which resolved any noise issues. They even hush a bit loud construction workers and protesters outside. I have see once somebody using orange ear plugs in the office, yet I it too risky, with headphones people might think your are just slightly eccentric audiophile

Comment: This was a great answer minus the last paragraph. The workplace doesn't have to bend around someone's inability to handle noise. If you can't handle the noise and everyone else is fine with it then it is on you to find a solution. Buying headphones is a pretty standard outcome for scenarios like this. Hell, this was a question directly out of an interview for my first employer "what would you do if some employees were being loud talking/tossing a ball around/whatever" and the standard answer is "I'd put on headphones." Offices aren't always quiet. Find a solution that only affects you.

Comment: About earplugs: they don't fully isolate the noise, they just reduce the noise level so it doesn't damage your hearing (I work in manufacturing, so I use them on a daily basis). It makes it *very* difficult to hear somebody speaking in a normal voice, and a person speaking loudly sounds as they're speaking normally - this is exactly what we do if we need somebody in a earplugs-enforced area to hear us.